# aws s3 commands in shell script and calling from php

Tags: php, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am having challenge with aws s3 commands using PHP. Here is the my requirements.

Write a shell script to download few files s3 bucket to local system using aws s3 cp.

**Shell Script (1.sh)**

```
#!/bin/bash 
aws s3 cp s3://bucket1/1.mp4 /tmp/1.mp4
```

When I run the above shell script (sh 1.sh or ./1.sh) the file downloaded with out any issues.

Now question is, I want to run the above shell script from PHP. Since the file name passing from from PHP. So, here is my php code.

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
$out = exec("sh /var/cronjobs/1.sh 2>&1");
echo $out;
?>
```

I am getting error like aws command not found. If I give full path of aws then getting a permission issue. I've already given full permission.

Comment: Can you copy here the permission issue error?

Comment: line 2: /root/bin/aws: Permission denied

Comment: Webserver needs access to the aws and the folder containing it.

Is the exec command allowed in php configuration?

Comment: Don't put the binary under `/root`. Unless you run your PHP script as root that won't work. Otherwise, please show the output of `ls -l /root/bin/aws`

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Dec 17 21:55 /root/bin/aws -> /root/.local/lib/aws/bin/aws

Comment: Webserver needs access to the aws and the folder containing it. Is the exec command allowed in php configuration?==> Yes

Comment: HI @favoretti, Can you please let me know how to change path of aws that can access by PHP?

Comment: Put it in `/usr/local/bin` or something like that.

Comment: Created symbolic or /usr/local/bin and still same issue

Comment: Beware! Never give root-privilegs to the webserver by allowing it access roots files or directorys. An attacke can use permissions to gain complete system ownership!

Better copy the binary to directory owned by the webserver, maybe in the webservers root protected by a .htaccess file

Comment: You can use this library for managing objects on AWS S3 using shell scripts https://github.com/aishwarydhare/universal-docs-manager